# How to redirect a page on successful sign in rails devise and after verify user== "teachers"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise

I want to redirect to a specific page on a successful sign in. Can anyone can advise me how to redirect after verification (userid == teacher). If userid is a teacher then redirect to the teacher page otherwise student page.

pbl01/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    :registrations => 'users/registrations'
  }

  resources :import,only: [:index,:create]
  root 'root#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

pbl01/app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      @userid = User.find_by(userid:params[:userid])

      if @userid.userid == 'teacher'
        redirect_to root_path
      else
       redirect_to timesset_path   
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
      render "new"  
    end
  end
end
```

pbl01/app/models/user.rb

```
require 'csv'

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :userid, :presence => true,
  validates :password, :presence => true,

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      users = find_by(userid: row["userid"]) || new
      users.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*updatable_attributes)
      users.password= row["password"]
      users.save!
    end
  end

  def self.updatable_attributes
    ["userid", "name", "email"]
  end
end
```

pbl01/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :userid %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :userid, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
        <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me %>
      </div>
    <% end -%>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: What is the column name in the CSV file that contains either "teacher" or "student"? If no column is available, how do you distinguish who is teacher and who is student?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use devise's after_sign_in_path_for(resource) method.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 if resource.userid == 'teacher'
    teacher_path(resource.id)
 else
    student_path(resource.id)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a column for position (if it is a student or a teacher).
In that way you can easily sort the successful login user and redirect it to the respective page where it should be.

Comment: please can you explain me how i will do it

Comment: @Mohammad you can set this [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html) as a reference at **2.2 Creating a Standalone Migration**